# Master/Detail ux logic with update/create

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, master-details

I am trying to wrap my mind around optimal ux logic and cant get to something i would be satisfied with.

I have thousands of entities which will never all be shown on the screen at once but there will be a search filter based on which some very limited set of entities would be shown (lets say 10-15 entities).

When user selects any entity in list, details pane should show edit form for all details of the entity.

Questions:

1. Lets say user searched for all entities whose name starts with 'abc' and then in details page he changes name to 'def' (thus entity doesnt fulfill search criteria, what is more logical thing to do? Should i just remove entity from master list? Or maybe reset search criteria to new name in order to show only updated entity? (just changing name but with all criteria seems very confusing)
2. When user searches for 'abc' and see those entities and then decide to create new entity (through popuo or new acreen, whatever create is), after create where is the best to point him? again, to old list he started with or to search criteria set to new name, newly created entity in master selected and full details shown in details pane?

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone would be able to answer this without extensive testing - I would suggest making the preview non editable and editing in an entirely new page to avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Thanks for your comment! Yes, feels like new page is the only clear way to avoid this particular problem. I just wanted to check if i am missing some pattern that actually might make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) an action should not start another (unexpected) action. If the user saves the new name, its just that. On a users point of view this has nothing to do with filtered list or even change filter criteria. So I would recommend not to reload the list oder change the criteria, because this is not what the users intention was, the intention was to change that particular value which in this case is part of the filter criteria but in other cases it might not. If the user want's to get rid of the renamed item in the list (this is a different action) it would be necessary to reapply the filter or change the criteria whatever the user intends to do. This way the user has the control over the situation.

2.) if a filter is applied and the user creates a new item which does not match the criteria the user has to be informed that the new item is saved and not shown in the list. A way to achieve this, is to show a message (not modal) that states, that the item is created but not shown. It is even possible to ad a link in the message to the newly created item. This message could be placed as fade in on top of the screen and then removed after a while, so the user has not to interact with this message at all, but is informed, why the new item is not shown in the list. (a tool that does that is JIRA)

These are two possibilities to handle this situation, but i think both would have to be testet with actual users.

Comment: thanks for this! i like the second idea very much, actually!